# How to fit general multivariate linear regression model (aka general linear model) for longitudinal data in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, panel-data, geepack

Let's consider a longitudinal data. Let $Y_{i}$ be the vector of $n$ repeated measurements for the $i$ th subject :
$$
\boldsymbol{Y}_{i}=\left(Y_{i 1}, Y_{i 2}, \ldots ,Y_{i n}\right)^{\prime}
$$

And we assume the following distribution for $\boldsymbol{Y}_{\boldsymbol{i}}$: $\quad \boldsymbol{Y}_{i} \sim N\left(X_{i} \boldsymbol{\beta}, \Sigma\right)$.

Usually, $\Sigma$ is just a general $(n \times n)$ covariance matrix. However, special structures for $\Sigma$ can be assumed (e.g., AR(1), exchangeable, etc).

Assuming independence across individuals, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and the parameters in $\Sigma$ can be estimated by maximizing
$$
L_{M L}=\prod_{i=1}^{N}\left\{(2 \pi)^{-n / 2}|\Sigma|^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-X_{i} \boldsymbol{\beta}\right)^{\prime} \Sigma^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-X_{i} \boldsymbol{\beta}\right)\right)\right\}
$$

My question is: Does there exist any package in R to fit this general multivariate linear model for longitudinal data?

Comment: Have a look at package `pglm` if it suits your needs.

Comment: I found that `gls()` function from `nlme` package does the job I want. But, since the `nlme` package is not updated regularly, and probably going to be obsolete soon, I am searching for a similar function in the package `geepack` or `lme4` that can be used to do the same job as `nlme::gls()`.